# convention for naming cleaned variable

Tags: sql, naming-conventions, naming

What is convention for naming transformed variable after cleaning it i.e. by removing some unwanted characters. I am asking about practical, colloquial suffix used in test environment. Let's say we have original dirty variable `item_name`.

I have come across endings like `item_name_cleaned`, `item_name_weeded_out`, `item_name_seeded_out`. What do you use?

Comment: For your purpose, `item_name_clean` seems appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

There's no convention, just use an expression clear enough or something that you've decided to standardize on in your work environment, and that you're sure everyone there knows.

But note that if this "cleaning" has any potential impact on security it's better to add suffixes to the **dirty** variables, to make their security risks evident to anyone using them.
Whether to do this *in addition* to the clean variables' suffix or not is more of a personal preference, but it's probably better to do both, so that one who encounters a variable without any such suffix is more likely to not make any assumptions about it.

That's only relevant when you *can* change the name of the original variable, of course (it's not a component or something that you otherwise can't interfere with).

Comment: You wrote there's no convention. How can you know with 100% level of confidence what millions of users do to their variables. Do you want to say that you have no convention and once you name the cleaned variable one way and the other time you name it the other way? By asking the question I hoped I can learn hints from experiences of other users. Cheers:-)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin 1/3 Are you serious? I wrote "there's no convention" because I read or at least skimmed a lot of books on general programming and have some experience and I've found no hint of a convention about this (a practice that's not even very widely used yet, either). This means that there's not a single practice that is followed by _most_ of the millions of developers in the world, or even that has a large prevalence other the other possible ones. (continues...)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin (...continues) 2/3 It does not mean that the individual persons use a different thing for every variable, every individual or shop that has to use this a lot will end up making their own convention, but it will be **their** **personal** convention. When you say _What is convention_ , working around the lack of grammar I have to assume that you're looking for a **universal** convention, not for a list of every single personal convention that all the developers and shops in the world ever came up with. That I don't have, I admit. (continues...)

Comment: @PrzemyslawRemin (...continues) 3/3 Among the possibilities that came up to my mind `safe` seems to have a slightly larger prevalence, if it applies to your case; `clean` is also used a lot. None of them seem to be anything close to a widely used "convention", though.